# No logs when exception is thrown in bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service

We have an ASP.Net Core v4 bot that we deployed to Azure. It works fine when using the testing feature in Azure. Then we deployed to MS Teams. It works find except every message is followed with another message saying "Sorry, it looks like something went wrong." That message is usually sent when an exception is thrown. I tried to go to Azure to see the logs, but it's not logging anything.

We do have `logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception.Message}");` in in our code, and I would think that it would log it somewhere when in production. So I turned on Application Insights for the bot, but it's not logging any exceptions. I tried streaming the logs from the web server, but it doesn't log anything when an exception is thrown.

I tried watching the application logs from the "Application logs" and "Web server logs"

Here is the code that handles errors:

```
public AdapterWithErrorHandler(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger, ConversationState conversationState = null)
    : base(configuration, logger)
{
    OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
    {
        // Log any leaked exception from the application.
        logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception.Message}");

        // Send a catch-all apology to the user.
        var errorMessage = MessageFactory.Text(ErrorMsgText, ErrorMsgText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(errorMessage);

        if (conversationState != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Delete the conversationState for the current conversation to prevent the
                // bot from getting stuck in a error-loop caused by being in a bad state.
                // ConversationState should be thought of as similar to "cookie-state" in a Web pages.
                await conversationState.DeleteAsync(turnContext);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Exception caught on attempting to Delete ConversationState : {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And here is the log settings for the app service for our bot:

[image]

Comment: is it not logging the exception because you are catching the exception?  if you want to log them yourselves you'd use the standard `trackException` methods in the various sdks (not sure how the bot framework exposes that though?)

Comment: Did you check in output window of the online code editor , present in Bot Management >> Build >>Open online code editor >> Output window.
where all the logs can be seen, also the exception. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AskYous I did some testing after my answer prior to its current edits. You *should* be able to see the errors in the logs. Are you not seeing anything at all? If you add code like I did below, does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohnGardner is correct. [Botframework catches all errors](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/e2c311fe413baa1b8e156c8a173381277b149071/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotAdapter.cs#L169), so you <strike>wouldn't</strike> may not see them in the typical Azure App Service logging.

@VinodkumarG is also correct that you can see the errors generated by `logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception.Message}");` in

`Bot Management >> Build >>Open online code editor >> Output window`

or

`https://<yourEndpoint>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/:vs.output`

---

**You actually should be able to see this in Log Stream > Application Logs**

I added this to my bot:

[image]

In testing:

[image]

In Output:

[image]

In Log Stream > Application Logs:

[image]

---

Our current recommended approach is to use Application Insights. You can use [Sample 21.Corebot-App-Insights](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/21.corebot-app-insights) as a guide. The primary modifications are how it adds App Insights in its [Startup.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/21.corebot-app-insights/Startup.cs):

**Full**

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.ApplicationInsights.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots;
using Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // Create the credential provider to be used with the Bot Framework Adapter.
            services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();

            // Add Application Insights services into service collection
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

            // Create the telemetry client.
            services.AddSingleton<IBotTelemetryClient, BotTelemetryClient>();

            // Add ASP middleware to store the http body mapped with bot activity key in the httpcontext.items. This will be picked by the TelemetryBotIdInitializer
            services.AddTransient<TelemetrySaveBodyASPMiddleware>();

            // Add telemetry initializer that will set the correlation context for all telemetry items.
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer>();

            // Add telemetry initializer that sets the user ID and session ID (in addition to other bot-specific properties such as activity ID)
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryBotIdInitializer>();

            // Create the telemetry middleware to track conversation events
            services.AddSingleton<IMiddleware, TelemetryLoggerMiddleware>();

            // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

            // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
            services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

            // Create the User state. (Used in this bot's Dialog implementation.)
            services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

            // Create the Conversation state. (Used by the Dialog system itself.)
            services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

            // The Dialog that will be run by the bot.
            services.AddSingleton<MainDialog>();

            // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
            services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogAndWelcomeBot<MainDialog>>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBotApplicationInsights();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

[Diff vs CoreBot](https://www.diffchecker.com/G4Spe85p)

You may also find this blog post useful: [Bot Analytics: Behind the Scenes](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/03/21/bot-analytics-behind-the-scenes/)